# Replacing elements of a list using other lists in Python

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have multiple lists `New, J,Pe_new`. I want to replace the locations of `New` mentioned in `J` with corresponding values in `Pe_new`. For instance, for `J[0]=1`, I want to replace `New[1]` with `Pe[0]=10`. But getting an error. I present the expected output.

```
import numpy as np

New=[1.5, 2.9, 2.7, 6.3, 5.5]


J=[1, 2, 4]
Pe_new=[10, 20, 30]

for i in range(0,len(J)):
    New=New[J[i]]
print(New)
```

The error is

```
in <module>
    New=New[J[i]]

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

The expected output is

```
[1.5, 10, 20, 6.3, 30]
```

Comment: It's `New[i] = Pe_new[i]`

Comment: when you do `New=New[J[i]]`, you assigned a value in the list `New` to `New` (the list is now no longer referenced and garbage collected). On the next iteration, you try to index into that element, but you can't, because it's now a `float` not a `list`

Comment: `New[J[i]] = Pe_new[i]`?

Comment: the better way to do this would be `for i, x in zip(J, Pe_new): New[i] = x`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yep, I mistyped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can zip the indices and the new values to iterate through them together and assign to `New` with the value and at the index in each iteration:

```
for index, value in zip(J, Pe_new):
    New[index] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use `zip` for iterating on both list simultaneously and performing your substituition.

```
for index,new_item in zip(J,Pe_new):
    New[index]=new_item
```

Answer (score 1):

The error makes complete sense as in the for loop you are trying to access an element of the `New` list by indexing it with a value from `J` i.e. `New[J[i]]`, which is not a valid operation since `New` is a list of floats and you cannot index a float.

You should do the following:

```py
import numpy as np

New=[1.5, 2.9, 2.7, 6.3, 5.5]

J=[1, 2, 4]
Pe_new=[10, 20, 30]

for i in range(0,len(J)):
    New[J[i]]=Pe_new[i]
    
print(New)
```